# Dynamic Rendered Condition for Programmatically Created JSF Component

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I am creating several JSF components programmatically to allow some form elements to be dynamically added to a page. Everything is going fine, but I've run into the wordy problem in the title.

I need to create an a4j:commandLink that has a dynamic rendered condition, like:

`#{myBean.shouldBeRendered}`

I can't see any way to assign a value expression to the rendered attribute on the class. It only seems to accept a straight boolean value, which won't work for me, since my rendered state will change later. Is there any workaround for this problem?

Comment: You can programmatically change the state of rendered attribute, later whenever you want. Whats the real deal ? Find a way to make the dynamic component programmatically attainable at any time. Or you can certainly use `f:param`, `f:attribute`, or a `f:setPropertyActionListener` component/value holders.

Comment: What do you mean by straight boolean value ? There are only two boolean value possible, `true` or `false`.

Comment: Correct, I just meant you could only set it to true or false at creation. Modifying the render condition in a server call is one alternative I've come up with, but isn't really ideal. It seems strange that you can set value/method expressions for every other attribute that can have them, other than this one?

Comment: _Modifying the render condition in a server call is one alternative I've come up with, but isn't really ideal._ You do it all the time you have an EL expression which links the user's client data to a server managed backing bean.

Comment: I agree that fundamentally it's not really different, but I have a multi-to-multi association of dynamic elements, so digging in and finding the one that I need to update the render condition for manually is far from ideal. Sadly, it sounds like what will have to be done. I was hoping I was overlooking something, as I've yet to find any comprehensive examples or documentation for programmatically creating Richfaces components. If anyone could provide that, I'd be eternally grateful.

Comment: Use HashMap to store your components. If you have the right search algorithm it can be very a fast finding.